# Defining functions which can take a lot of parameters in C#

Tags: c#, function, parameters

For example, `printf` in c can take any number of parameters like `printf("%d %d %s %s...",a,b,c,d,...`) and is documented as below

```
printf( const char *format [, argument]... );
```

How can I define such functions in C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword:

```
void WriteAll(params object[] args) {
   for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
       Console.WriteLine(args[i]);
}
```

args will be an array with all the arguments you pass. Note that it must be the last formal argument.

Answer (score 1):

use params object[] arg as the last argument.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
see for more detail

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Print(params object[] values)
    {
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

this code will print to the console every item you'll send at the object array using the "params" keyword. you can call this method with as many parameters you like (or none).

link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

in c# the you'll use the **[params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)** key word.

```
public static void UseParams2(params object[] list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass an object with your parameters

```
private void MyVoid(MyParameterObject params)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches in this case:

- You can define a `type` that holds all fields you need to pass and return between methods. Better then simple `object array`, cause it's typesafe.
- You can define dictionary where place parameter names and values. Better then simple `object array`, cause it's typesafe.
- (This depends on quantity of the parameters, and on use logic of the code) You can define overrloads of the same function.

  ```
  func A (AA aa) 

  func A(AA aa, BB bb =null)

  func A(AA aa, BB bb = null, CC cc = null)
  ```

and so on...